# Intellij (java) run/debug configuration "No main class not specified" Azure Functions

Tags: java, azure, intellij-idea, azure-functions

I have a Intellij Java project with an Azure Functions HttpTrigger in it (API endpoint, basically).

I have some environment variables that I wanted to add to the `Run/Debug Configuration` on IntelliJ via the `Run > Edit Configurations > Application` on the main toolbar at the top. I wanted to pass the environment variables here, so I don't have to save them inside Windows, but its saying "no main class is specified" but I don't have any main method here (public static void main(String[] args)) because this is just a repo with an Azure function inside of it.
[image]

How can I launch this configuration and bypass this message? If I'm able to bypass this, and starting up this project by running `func start` in the terminal, should that command go in the `VM options` box?

Comment: Why dont u try writing a main class and call your azure function from there ?

Comment: This run configuration is meant to be used for running applications that have `public static void main(String[] args))` method. Seems that you need Azure-specific run configuration here. Refer to related [MS Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/java/toolkit-for-intellij/quickstart-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @Andrey said in the comment, **run configuration** is meant to be used for running applications that have public static void main(String[] args)) method. That's why you got `No Main class specified error`.

If you want to add environment variables, you can add them to `local.settings.json` file. They are stored in the environment variables.

[image]

Reference:

[Create your first Azure function with Java and IntelliJ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij)

https://medium.com/awesome-azure/azure-reading-application-settings-in-azure-functions-asp-net-core-1dea56cf67cf